# 0 days left in cycle of evernote at the start of the month?

Tags: evernote

Today is the 2nd of November 2012, and I see this in my Evernote account:

[image]

I believe that the cycle is a monthly cycle, and I must be having around 28 days left in it at the moment. What's from?

I am seeing "0 days" continuously from past few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just contact the support. They are helpful and they respond fast.
Source? They already helped me out a plenty of times when I had my own questions.